# MySQL suddenly not starting

Tags: mysql

Here is the LOGfile

```
2022-08-08 14:10:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: The first innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' did not exist. A new tablespace will be created!

2022-08-08 14:10:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

2022-08-08 14:10:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes

2022-08-08 14:10:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11

2022-08-08 14:10:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1

2022-08-08 14:10:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions

2022-08-08 14:10:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 2G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M

2022-08-08 14:10:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2022-08-08 14:10:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp7\mysql\data\ibdata1' size to 10 MB. 
Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...

2022-08-08 14:10:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp7\mysql\data\ibdata1' size is now 10 MB.

2022-08-08 14:10:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file D:\xampp7\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 536870912 bytes

2022-08-08 14:10:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file D:\xampp7\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 536870912 bytes

2022-08-08 14:10:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file D:\xampp7\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to D:\xampp7\mysql\data\ib_logfile0

2022-08-08 14:10:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=11451

2022-08-08 14:10:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new

2022-08-08 14:10:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created

2022-08-08 14:10:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.

2022-08-08 14:10:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.

2022-08-08 14:10:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.

2022-08-08 14:10:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating sys_virtual system tables.

2022-08-08 14:10:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables

2022-08-08 14:10:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp7\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...

2022-08-08 14:10:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp7\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.

2022-08-08 14:10:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start

2022-08-08 14:10:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 0; transaction id 7

2022-08-08 14:10:52 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2022-08-08 14:10:52 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  '.\mysql\plugin'

2022-08-08 14:10:52 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  '.\mysql\servers'

2022-08-08 14:10:52 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I was working yesterday, today I try to start mysql and got this. In this case i didn't see the "error" msg that i was having before `[ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded` searching solutions

- I deleted the aria_logs FILES but its the same
- I renamed ib_logfile1, ib_logfile0, ib_buffer_pool but its the same.
- I'v try this too:

```
"D:\xampp7\mysql\bin\aria_chk.exe -r mysql/*.mai"
D:\xampp7\mysql\bin\aria_chk.exe: Got error 'Can't find file' when trying to use aria control file '.\aria_log_control'
aria_chk.exe: error: You don't have permission to use 'mysql/*.mai'
```

(Im using it like Administrator)

Please help! Thanks

---

Comment: You might deleted something accidentally. Better re-install it.

Comment: something like... ¿? any idea ??
reinstalling service and keeping DB thats possible ? I'v had big work DB and dont want to lose it

Comment: Looks like your old database was deleted and you moved only the "data" directories to a new location or something like that. How do you know that MySQL is not running? Looks like it is running but only in IPV6.

Comment: but I didn't delete anything also didn't moved any directories